# Is it possible to use a block tag ({% block %}) from base html template two or more times in derived html file in Django

Tags: django

I want to be able to reuse the same block tag multiple times in derived html.
something like:

base.html

```
<body>  
    {% block panel %}  
         # some basic panel structure inside this block  
    {% endblock %}  
</body>
```

derived.html

```
{% extends base.html %}
```

--first panel

```
<div class="col">  
    {% block panel %}  
        # override things like panel header  
    {% endblock %}  
</div>
```

--second panel

```
<div class="col">  
    {% block panel %}  
        # again override some panel stuff from base template  
    {% endblock %}  
</div>
```

Is there anyway i can achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will result in template syntax error. The best you can do is to include as many block tags as you require in base and reuse them. Or you can even loop the blocks in base.

I haven't tested it out, but theoretically it should work. In your base, create a loop block, in below example it creates 6 blocks, block content1.....  content6

```
{% for i in '123456' %}

{% block content{{i}} %}

Foo

{% endblock content{{i}} %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. The best way to do it is, assign each block for each panel or if you have multipanel then run the loop for the block.

In your current case (i assuming two panel in single derived file) it would be like this-

## base.html

```
<body>  
    {% block content %}  
        <!-- all your panels -->
    {% endblock %}  
</body>
```

## derived.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}  
　<div class="col">  
      <!-- First panel -->
      <!-- Second panel -->
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

> The block is just for reducing the redundant work which unique to each extended file. so you can only referred it to single time in any extended file.